# A fatal error with 8-bit quantization in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, quantization

I'm trying to run quantization model in Tensorflow using Bazel with my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

I ran the following command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph
```

and here is the error:

> ERROR: /tensorflow-master/tensorflow/contrib/verbs/BUILD:136:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/verbs:rdma' failed (Exit 1).
>
> In file included from tensorflow/contrib/verbs/rdma.cc:18:0:
>   ./tensorflow/contrib/verbs/rdma.h:21:30: fatal error: infiniband/verbs.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> Target //tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph failed to build

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `libibverbs-dev` using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libibverbs-dev
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ran the command you suggested and the above problem was gone but there occurred a new error:  `fatal error: rdma/rdma_cma.h: No such file or directory`, how can I fix it? It seems that  I need to install some things to make it work smoothly ?

Comment: Try installing RDMA cm library from https://github.com/ofiwg/librdmacm Follow the README instructions.

Answer (score 1):

installing `libibverbs-dev` and `librdmacm-dev` using

```
sudo apt-get install libibverbs-dev
sudo apt-get install librdmacm-dev
```